# Aggregate Javadocs and Maven Release Plugin on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

Is there a fool-proof way to generate **aggregate** Javadocs for a multi-module Maven reactor project in a Jenkins job using the Maven Release Plugin Plugin?

My problem is, after the `maven-release-plugin` has updated all POM versions, the next build will break since `javadoc:aggregate` fails on the reactor POM, given that the referenced versions of the module artifacts do not yet exist.

My workaround is to run the build once with the `maven-javadoc-plugin` disabled, using a profile. Then after re-enabling the `maven-javadoc-plugin` the next build will pass.

This is rather a hack, and I wonder if I'm just missing anything simple...

Here is my `maven-javadoc-plugin` configuration from the reactor POM:

```
    <profile>
        <id>javadoc</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>aggregate-javadoc</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>aggregate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing same issue and after a bit of playing with it, it turned out that using `aggregate-jar` goal instead works just fine (it generates basic aggregated javadoc and in addition jar file, but the latter can be discarded).

I think this is cause by the different default lifecycle phases to which goal execution is bound and additional execution of `generate-sources` phase in case of `aggregate` phase:

- [javadoc:aggregate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html): *Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `generate-sources` prior to executing itself.*
- [javadoc:aggregate-jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-jar-mojo.html): *Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: `package`.*